# Conversion of text in column to a dataframe

Tags: r, tm

I have text data in the column of a data set as follow

```
UNIQUEID Cloumn1
1        FG
2        PR FG RT
3        FG BR UP DR ST
....
```

I want to convert the column of data into a data frame  so that the output is as under and these texts (FG, RN, etc) become variables

```
UNIQUEID   FG  PR RT BR UP DR ST
1           1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2           1  1  1  0  0  0  0
3           1  0  0  1  1  1  1
......
```

I have tried TM package to convert as under

```
corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(weather$codesum))
corpus = tm_map(corpus, tolower)
corpus = tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus = tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
corpus = tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
dtm =  DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
dtm = as.data.frame(as.matrix(dtm))
colnames(dtm) = make.names(colnames(dtm))
str(dtm)

data.frame:   20517 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ prfg: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

when I see the output I find only one variable. Where as I want all the text as variables.

Please suggest solution

Comment: UNIQUEID Cloumn1 1 FG 2 PR FG RT 3 FG BR UP DR ST ....

Answer (score 0):

If you like `tidyr` and `dplyr` you can try this solution too:

```
# libraries
library (tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# your data
t <- "UNIQUEID,Cloumn1
1,FG
2,PR FG RT
3,FG BR UP DR ST"

df <- read.table(text=t, header = T, sep=',', stringsAsFactors=F)

# The interesting part
df %>%
  transform(                         # trasforms each string in an array
    Cloumn1 = strsplit(Cloumn1, " ")
    ) %>%
  unnest(Cloumn1) %>%                # for each string in Cloumn1 creates a row
  mutate(v = 1) %>%                  # let's add a dummy 1
  spread(Cloumn1, v, fill= 0)        # rows become columns and NA is replaced by 0
```